# Simple Django Search Form Just Won't Work

Tags: django, search

I just don't understand what's going on here and I've spent a lot of time attempting to debug this thing (which I took directly from a Django book). The search funcationality actually DID work the first time I loaded the site.  I then had to do some debugging to make other pieces work and the search functionality suddenly broke.

When I submit the form, I get 404 telling me that the "story does not exist" although it is in fact in saved in my admin (and therefore my database). The Get query appended to the URL seems right.  It concatenates multiple words.

I know that this is so simple and it actually worked before I don't get it.  Also interesting, the book that I took this code from didn't include a second Q after the pipe (|).  I thought that was a typo and whenever I try to remove it, the whole site fails (including the admin template).  That's also strange.

```
from cms.models import Story, Category
from django.db.models import Q
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404

def search(request):
     if 'q' in request.GET:
         term = request.GET['q']
         story_list = Story.objects.filter(
             Q(title__contains=term) | Q(markdown_content__contains=term))
         heading = "Search results"
     return render_to_response("cms/story_list.html", locals())
```

Comment: The indentations (in my code) are correct.  I realize I messed up the indentations in the example provided

Comment: Your code doesn't raise a `404` anywhere, so maybe there's a problem with your `urls.py` configuration...

Comment: I don't know, I copied the urls.py exactly from the book and the rest of the app is working just fine urlpatterns+=patterns('project.cms.views', 
 url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'category', name="cms-category"), 
 url(r'^search/$', 'search', name="cms-search"), 
)
e.

Comment: Sorry, that's heinously ugly.  But the action in my form is pointed to "{% url cms-search %}", so that seems right as well.  Really can't figure this out, especially since it originally worked

Comment: Where is the 404 raised?? And what happens when you print the query result (use development server to see print output)?

Comment: Hi AndiDog, I'm a noob so bare with me.  Is this the print output you're referring to? Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://localhost/cms/search/?q=first+

No story found matching the query

Comment: Set `DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True` in your settings and then start `manage.py runserver`. Then the development server (on "localhost:8000" by default) will show you a traceback if the 404 was raised due to an exception. You can also use print statements in your code for debugging, like `print story_list`. Check what the output and the stacktrace is in order to see where the problem is.

Comment: Alright then find out which `get_object_or_404` call results in that 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if 'q' in request.GET:
    q = request.GET['q']
    if not q:
        errors.append('Enter a search term.')
    else:
        storylist = Story.objects.filter(title__icontains=q)
        return render_to_response('search_result.html',
           {'packages': packages, 'query': q})
    return render_to_response('cms/story_list.html', {'errors': errors})
```

Answer (score 2):

That is the problem of urlpattern, when the url is `http://localhost:8000/cms/search/?q=sec`, it will match the urlpattern `url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'object_detail', info_dict, name="cms-story")`, then the program will find the story whose name like `q` or whose `markdown_content` like `q`, but now your database has not the story, therefore it will tell you "story does not exist", now you can do it like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from cms.models import Story

info_dict = {'queryset':Story.objects.all(), 'template_object_name':'story'}

urlpatterns = patterns('cmsproject.cms.views',
    url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'category', name="cms-category"),
    url(r'^search/$', 'search', name="cms-search"),
)
urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.generic.list_detail',
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'object_detail', info_dict, name="cms-story"),
    url(r'^$', 'object_list', info_dict, name="cms-home"),
)
```